# Visual Basic 6.0 Data Layer code generator

Tags: vb6

I need a code generator for data layer in visual basic 6.0 , having a CRUD functionality with SP interaction?

Comment: You've found an excellent reason to not use VB6 anymore. Any chance you could use a modern programming language? They tend to have this sort of thing built-in.

Comment: @John Saunders- I required to use VB 6.0 to the application they assigned to me, so I have no option but to accept this project using vb 6.0

Comment: or there is a conversion tool from vb.net to vb 6.0?

Comment: @user: you have options. Suicide is one of them. Quitting is another. Calling code written in a modern language from VB6 code is a third.

Comment: @user: you don't need a conversion tool. You can create COM objects using VB.NET. These objects can be consumed like any other COM object from VB6 (or even from VBScript). There are very few excuses for still writing VB6 code.

Comment: the problem if I had to create a com using vb.net, is that, I need to install the .net framework on the machine of each user, is that correct?

Comment: @John Saunders: What's with the attitude when people ask questions about VB 6? We get that you're not a fan of it, and you probably have some useful suggestions (like the third option proposed), but you need to understand that there are a lot of applications with code already written in VB 6 that can't be ported at the moment for whatever reason(s). In light of that, your comments seem more infuriating than helpful.

Comment: @Cody: 1) It's dead. 2) He's doing new work with it, not maintenance. Maintenance:ok, though should consider replacement;new dev: very bad, don't do it.

Comment: @user: depending on which OS version your users are running, you might have to install it, if it hasn't already been installed for some other reason. Also, there are easy ways to ensure .NET gets installed, including the same install process you'll use to install the COM object. It's usually not an issue.

Comment: @John Saunders: I'm more than a little bit tired of this attitude myself.  If you're not interested in VB6 then just stay out of threads on the topic.  Frankly this looks like just cause for moderation to me, it's nothing but flaming.

Comment: @Bob: nonsense. I've presented alternatives to this real problem - organizations doing new work with VB6 when they don't have to. Have you presented any alternative beyond continuing to use obsolete development environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that may help you is the [ADO Stored Procedure Generator](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=103) at vbrad.com.  According to the site, the addin "automates the task of mapping stored procedure parameters to ADO Command object parameters".  I haven't tried it myself, but the feedback looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MyGeneration.  It's a free tool and works very well.  You'll need a template to generate the code you want.  It doesn't currently have any for VB that I can see, but you can write your own or modify one of the many existing templates (it's easy).  You can also use the VB.NET or C# templates and then create .NET assemblies, expose them as COM libraries and call them from VB6.  One of these options should work for you.

MyGeneration web page:

- http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx

Download the program from the download.com link on that page.

If you choose to modify or write your own templates, I recommend reading my super awesome tutorial here.

- http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/spgilmore/archive/2009/12/03/getting-started-with-mygeneration-a-primer-and-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i used a program called vb_net_maker. even though the original site is no longer available, you might still be able to find copies of the program on the web. Its not free though, but i cant say how much is costs.